# pointer being assigned values with a loop

Tags: c, loops, pointers, scanf

I am trying to make an array with 10 pointers which will receive the input from `scanf` within a for loop. Then I want to call that list. However, I get a runtime error for memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char * string[10];
    //printf("%s", *string[0]);
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("what is string");
        scanf("%s", string[i]);
        printf("%s", string[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No wonder, you have no memory allocated for the string, but shooting with wild pointers at elephants. Please read about pointers and memory allocation. You are missing the very basics - no offense.

Comment: *What is string ? Pointers don't hurt me...*

Comment: when calling scanf() : 1) with a '%s' format string, always include a max length modifier, I.E.  scanf( "%25s", string[i] ); (even this will fail unless a memory allocation of at least 26 chars was performed for each of the 10 string pointers.)  2) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  in this case, ==1 is success 3) the %s format specifier stops when encountering any white space (like the newline) so the posted code (scanf) will fail after the first iteration. suggest " %25s" (note leading space)

Answer (score 3):

You need to think about the data structure with which you are attempting to store your strings.

```
char * string[10];
```

This declares an array of 10 elements of type "char *" or "pointer to a char".

Now think about what you are doing with this operation.

```
scanf("%s", string[i]);
```

You are using scanf to attempt to read user input.  Does your function call make sense though?

1. The first parameter is your format string. "%s" makes sense because you want the user to provide you a string.  Let's ignore the fact that you have not put any bounds on the length of that input for the moment.
2. Your second parameter needs to be be the variable where you want to store the input.  You have provided "string[i]".  Remember that in C, strings are just char arrays.  However, your variable "string[i]" has the type "char *".  This doesn't make sense.  How can you store data of type "char array[]" in variable of type "char * array[]"?  The types are different.

You need to create a buffer within which you can store your input string.  Something like:

```
char buffer[256];
```

Then you call scanf like:

```
scanf("%s", buffer);
```

Keep in mind that this isn't the best idea because you don't know how many characters the user might enter.  This will take the input character array and store them in a variable that correctly represents that data.

Note that this call would be safer:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(char), stdin);
```

fgets will read a fixed number of characters from the stream.  In the above call I define that number by just taking the length of my buffer variable.  I divide by sizeof(char) just to make sure that any strange representation issues where a char != 1 byte are taken care of.  Also note that you will end up with the carraige return in your buffer (fgets will grab it).

Once you have your string in an appropriate variable, you can save it and get a pointer to a copy of that string with:

```
char * ptr = strdup(buffer);
```

This will create a new copy of the string stored in buffer and return a pointer to that new copy location.  This pointer can then go into your array.

Note that you cannot just do:

```
string[i] = buffer
```

Because string[i] is just a pointer to the buffer variable...which will be overwritten during each iteration!  You would end up with an array of pointers to the same variable, which would all end up giving you to the same string (the last input).

Put it all together in something like this:

```
char buffer[256];
printf("What is your string? ");
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(char), stdin);
string[i] = strdup(buffer);
```

Because strdup() uses a malloc under the hood, you will need to free all your strings at the end of your program with:

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < sizeof(string)/sizeof(char *); i++) {
   if(string[i]) free(string[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either allocate memeory dynamically or make your 2-d array:

```
char string[10][100];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to allocate memory -

```
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  string[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*10); 
  }
```

So that your program does not give error.
But after this you have to free the memory allocated.